# Laravel query builder - dynamic table name

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Is there a way I could make a dynamic query?
For example:

```
$table_var = 'transactions';
DB::table($table_var)->whereRaw('id=?','1');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with "dynamic query"?

```
$users = DB::table($tableName)->where('name', $name)->get();
```

In this case you can change dynamically $tablename and also the variable $name, so you can catch everything you need. Also you can use a variable in the first parameter of the method where().
So if you want to dynamically change the table name you can do something like this:

```
$names = ['users', 'posts', 'comments'];
foreach($name as $names){
$res= DB::table($tableName)->where('active', 1)->get();
// do something with the result
}
```

I don't know if I answered your question.

Comment: Is it safe from SQL injection to set table name dynamically this way? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi. I don't see problems with that (as logn as you have full controll of the variable)